# Best render settings for broadcast/4k TV

Tags: after-effects, broadcasting, 4k, television

I see a lot of tips for getting h264 renders onto web streaming sites in 4K but not much on TV. Should I just go with Animation/lossless for my “master”? seems crazy for a 22 minute program but HDD is cheap now so it’s doable. The content consists of detailed animation including 3d rendered scenes source material.

*Would 4k on h264 5.2 be adequate? Any artifacts going h264 -> broadcast?*

Answer (score 3):

The reason for mastering out to an uncompressed / minimally lossy format is so that you have a master copy, which you can then use to make other copies, without generation loss, or having to re-render.

**You don't have to use Animation**. There, I've said it. While it's mathematically lossless, it's only 8-bit, so swings ± roundabouts. While I used to only ever render Aniamtion ever, these days I prefer [DNxHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNxHR_codec) or [Cineform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CineForm) with 10-bit colour, the file size is better and you have four times as much colour information. If you're on a mac [ProRes 4444](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_ProRes) is a good option.

But the first step is **check with the broadcaster** to see what their tech specs are. The broadcaster where I work mostly take ProRes, so I make proRes submasters from my master copy using ffmpeg. No seriously, check, because they will reject stuff that doesn't pass their quality control.